# unstable memory allocation in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm getting unstable results with my software and wanted to understand why and how I should modify my code to get consistent results. To show this, I prepared a mock sample of the software; below, I have 2 main classes, `Mother` and `Daughter`; these are my main data structures, and I use `Mother` in many other data structures. Hence, it's essentially an abstract class but can not be purely abstract since some of the observables are also directly dependent on it, so I can not write (as far as I know) pure virtual functions in it. Classes are defined as follows;

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Mother {
    private:
        double some_var_;

    public:
        Mother() {some_var_ = 0.;}

        virtual ~Mother() {}

        virtual void print() const
        {
            std::cout << "printing from mother " << some_var_ << std::endl;
        }

        virtual void setvar(double v) {some_var_ = v;}

        virtual const double var() const {return 0.;}
};

class Daughter : public Mother
{
    private:
        double new_var_;

    public:
        Daughter() {new_var_ = 0.;}

        virtual ~Daughter() {}

        void print() const
        {
            std::cout << "printing from Daughter " << new_var_ << std::endl;
        }

        void setvar(double v) {new_var_=v;}

        const double var() const {return new_var_;}
};
```

I interact with these data structures through a `collection` class defined as follows;

```cpp
class collection
{
    private:
        std::vector<Daughter> daughters_;

    public:
        collection () {Reset();}

        virtual ~collection() {}

        void Reset() {daughters_.clear();}

        Daughter* GetNewDaughter()
        {
            daughters_.push_back(Daughter());
            return &daughters_.back();
        }

        const std::vector<Daughter>& daughters() {return daughters_;}
};
```

Given these, I defined a `filter` function to trim these data structures;

```cpp
template <class T, typename FN>
std::vector<const T*> filter(std::vector<T> objects, FN func)
{
    std::vector<const T*> filtered;
    for (auto &obj: objects)
    {
        if (func(&obj)) filtered.push_back(&obj);
    }
    return filtered;
}
```

And the code body is as follows;

```cpp
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    collection* col = new collection();
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        Daughter* current = col->GetNewDaughter();
        current->setvar(double(i)*2.);
    }

    std::vector<const Daughter*> filt1 = filter(col->daughters(),
                [] (const Daughter* d) {return d->var() > 2.;});

    std::vector<const Daughter*> filt2;
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<col->daughters().size(); i++)
    {
        const Daughter * current = &(col->daughters())[i];
        if (current->var() > 2.) filt2.push_back(current);
    }

    std::cout << "first filtered" << std::endl;
    for (const Daughter * c: filt1) c->print();
    std::cout << "second filtered" << std::endl;
    for (const Daughter * c: filt2) c->print();

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I defined two filters, one with the `filter` function and the other manually, which I expect to see the same result. However, I run the code 4 times, and each time, I got different results;

```sh
g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -O3 -fPIC main.cpp -o main
$ ./main
first filtered
printing from Daughter 4
printing from Daughter -2.68156e+154
Segmentation fault: 11
$ ./main
first filtered
printing from Daughter 4
printing from Daughter 0
Segmentation fault: 11
$ ./main
first filtered
printing from Daughter 4
printing from Daughter 2.31584e+77
Segmentation fault: 11
$ ./main
first filtered
printing from Daughter 4
printing from Daughter 6
printing from Daughter 8
second filtered
printing from Daughter 4
printing from Daughter 6
printing from Daughter 8
```

As you can see, the first 3 runs are completely rubbish for some reason, and the last one is as expected, but it seems to be completely random, so I believe I'm doing something wrong during the memory allocation. I would appreciate it if someone can show me what and why I am doing wrong and how should I change the code to avoid such instability.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change:

```
std::vector<const T*> filter(std::vector<T> objects, FN func)
```

to

```
std::vector<const T*> filter(const std::vector<T>& objects, FN func)
```

imho, you create new instance (copy) of vector when you call filter.
You 'filter' that new instance of vector, after the filter finishes the vector is deleted and, as result, std::vector<const Daughter*> filt1 has invalid pointers.

Comment: Also might want to consider using `std::copy_if`.

Comment: Thanks @Evgeny unfortunatelly I'm getting the following error when I apply your suggestion: `main.cpp:91:42: error: no matching function for call to 'filter'
    std::vector<const Daughter*> filt1 = filter(col->daughters(),`.

Comment: Let you try: std::vector<const T*> filter(const std::vector<T>& objects, FN func)

Answer (score 2):

Evgeny was right. Just a small description of the problem. The thing is `filter` function returns the vector of pointers to the temporary objects that have been created on calling `filter` function (the first argument - vector). After the function finished his work, `filt1` stores invalid pointers to the destroyed objects.